# How to use FAL in TypoScript with level sliding features?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm struggeling with this `TypoScript` code which doesn't work anymore in `TYPO3 6.2.x` because the result is now a `File ID` instead of the `File Path`:

```
temp.header-image = TEXT
temp.header-image {
    value = {$imagePath}header-01.jpg
    wrap = <style type="text/css"> #header-image { background: #FFF url('|') no-repeat left top;}</style>
    stdWrap.override.data = levelmedia : -1, slide
    stdWrap.override.wrap = uploads/media/|
    stdWrap.override.required = 1
}
```

The above TypoScript outputs;

```
[..]url('uploads/media/2101') [..]
```

This should be;

```
[..]url('uploads/media/SomeFileName.jpg') [..]
```

I have also looked at the snippets
on http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2014/03/30/typo3-6-2-probleme-mit-ressourcen-media-auslesen/ but couldn't make it worked with just retrieving the file path instead of a full image (and with keeping the level slide features).

How can I get this TypoScript snippet working with a relation to FAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uploads/media` is a relict from the time resources were copied into that folder. Therefore prepending your resource with it is wrong.

"2101" is the ID of the file reference you got from the Media field. You need to resolve this reference to your actual file:

```
temp.header-image = IMG_RESOURCE
temp.header-image {
  file {
    import.data = levelmedia: -1, slide
    treatIdAsReference = 1
  }
  stdWrap.wrap = <style type="text/css"> #header-image { background: #FFF url('|') no-repeat left top;}</style>
}
```

The essential part here is `treatIdAsReference` which tells TYPO3 that the uid provided (in your example "2101") is a file reference (table `sys_file_reference`). This file reference is then resolved to the actual file (table `sys_file`). Because it's cObject of typo `IMG_RESOURCE`, TYPO3 takes care of resolving the path to the file.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfect, I was nearby the answer but didnt use the IMG_RESOURCE object.